# ListView black onScroll

Tags: android, android-listview

This is my first time on this site.
I will ask you to help me to resolve a bug.

I have a ListView on my Android Activity. When i scroll it the background of each text will be black until i click on one of the items.
How i can fix it???

IMG BEFORE SCROLL: http://gestorespese.altervista.org/Schermata_del_2012-04-01_11_43_27.png
IMG AFTER SCROLL: http://gestorespese.altervista.org/Schermata_del_2012-04-01_11_43_34.png

Comment: welcome! please show us some code/layout so we can try to help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Xml file which contains the listview Cache color hint to #00000000

for example

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listVIew);
lv.setCacheHintColor("#00000000")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!
You have fix my BUG...